# Cannot get button click to work in Electron App

Tags: node.js, button, input, electron, dom-events

I've followed the guidance at https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload with a little twist to have the "pong" response display as a button's text in my form.  Here is my renderer.js code (working):

```
const func = async () => {
    const response = await window.versions.ping()
    document.querySelector('#closeBtn').value = response
}
  
func()

/*
document.querySelector('#closeBtn').addEventListener('click', async () => {
    func()
})
*/

/*
document.querySelector('#closeBtn').addEventListener('click', async () => {
    const response = await window.versions.ping()
    document.querySelector('#closeBtn').value = response
})
*/
```

Again, this WORKS.  The form will appear with the "Cancel" button already labelled "pong" instead of "Cancel".

What I can't seem to figure out is how to get the same code to run only after I click the "Cancel" button,

```
<input id="closeBtn" type="button" value="Cancel">
```

...as defined in my index.html.

If I uncomment either of the commented functions in my renderer.js above (after commenting out "func()", nothing happens when I click "Cancel".

I've also tried in my HTML:

```
<input id="closeBtn" type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="func()">
```

...and nothing.  The ONLY way it works is almost perfectly "by the book".  Why doesn't anything happen for the onclick?

In summary: If you refer to my commented out code, I tried each of the commented blocks in sequence after commenting out the "func()" line.  I also tried adding the onclick item directly to the button code in html.